# Is there an elegant way of checking whether at least one element has a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements, and I want to check whether at least one has the class `demo_control`

The following code works. Is there a more elegant way?

```
    var a='f_date1,f_date2,f_date3,f_date4,f_field1,f_field2'.split(',');
    var flag=false;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if ($('#'+a[i]).hasClass('demo_control')) {
            flag=true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) says:

> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

So no need to loop explicitly; just select the elements in one go, and apply the method on that selection:

```
let flag = $('#f_date1,#f_date2,#f_date3,#f_date4,#f_field1,#f_field2').hasClass('demo_control');
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be a possible elegant solution

```
const ids = 'f_date1,f_date2,f_date3,f_date4,f_field1,f_field2';
const query = ids.split(',').map(el => `#${el}.demo_control`).join(', ');
const flag = $(query).length > 0;
```

What I've done is just created a single selector for you ids with class. And check if there are any elementa matching this selector.

Answer (score 1):

If `demo_control` is unique to these fields, why not do:

`flag = $(".demo_control").length > 0`

Comment: Great solution. In my particular case demo_control is not unique to these fields

Comment: not gonna get much better than @trincots answer then!

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to do to get a class count...

```
flag=document.getElementsByClassName('demo_control').length>0;
```